# Styling javafx checkbox

Tags: java, javafx

I've tried to apply the following styles to my CheckBox

```
.check-box .box {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-shadow-highlight-color, -fx-outer-border, -fx-inner-border, -fx-white;
}

.check-box:selected .mark {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-colour-white;
}

.check-box:selected .box {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-blue;
}
```

The goal is to have a white checkbox with grey border and when the checkbox is checked to have a blue background and white tick. When I apply these styles I get the result I want. However an odd thing happens when doing the following steps:
1- click on checkbox to select
2- click on checkbox to deselect
The checkbox disappears and will only appear again if I click on somewhere else in the pane.

You can see the images below of the checkbox when it is first rendered then when it is checked.

[image: Checkbox in normal state][image: Selected Checkbox][image: Deselected Checkbox]

Comment: Your css seems wrong, I'm getting `WARNING: Could not resolve '-fx-white' while resolving lookups for '-fx-background-color' from rule '*.check-box *.box'`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I do not think that the problem comes from your **StyleSheets**, I think it's due to a bad manipulation in your **Java code**, you said :

> The checkbox disappears and will only appear again if I click on somewhere else in the **pane**

So start with your **Pane**, look at whether there is a related event, and concerning the style, your method is **almost** correct, this is how I would have proceeded :

```
.check-box .box {

-fx-background-color: white;
-fx-border-color:grey;
-fx-border-radius:3px; 

}

.check-box:selected .mark {

-fx-background-color: white;

}

.check-box:selected .box {

-fx-background-color: #28a3f4;
}
```

Good luck !